# C# - How to open a Windows Form in DLL

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, dll

I have two programs: `DesktopApp1` and `DesktopApp2`. Both of them are Windows Forms but the first one outputs to *Class library* (.dll) and the second one references it.

**Form 1 (dll):**

```
namespace DesktopApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void generate()
        {
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = @"C:/Users/me/rel1.rpt";
        }
    }
}
```

**Form 2:**

```
// ...
using DesktopApp1;

namespace DesktopApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DesktopApp1.Form1 r = new DesktopApp1.Form1();
            // The Form 1 window doesn't opens. Nothing happens.
            r.generate();
        }
    }
}
```

**What I expect:**

User clicks on `button1` of **Form 2** and a new **Form 1** (DLL) window opens executing the `generate` method.

**What actually happens:**

User clicks on `button1`, the mouse cursor change to loading state and nothing appears on screen.

What I'm possibly doing wrong? There's any other approach to convert a Windows Form to DLL and open it from another program?

Comment: Use Debug > Break All, Debug > Windows > Threads and verify that the Main thread is selected.  Look at the Call Stack window to see what it is doing.  Contact SAP for support when you somewhat inevitably conclude that CrystalReports is not working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Form.Show(...) or Form.ShowDialog(...) methods.

Comment: You should make use of MSDN for this type of information (it will give you a lot more details), or just use the Intellisense built-in to Visual Studio. The arguments are all optional, so you can call either method without parameters. (EDIT: Previous comment I was replying to was deleted)